# How to get the text inputs value from the modal in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am studying Angular now and I am creating a modal form in my page. In my page I have 2 controllers the first one is from displaying the list and the second is from my modal controller.

My problem is I can't get the value from the modal.

Here's some of my codes:

```
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        ... table here
        </div>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent">
        <div ng-form="noteForm" ng-controller="NoteCtrl">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Add New Note</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12" ng-class="{'has-error': noteForm.c_subject.$invalid && noteForm.c_subject.$touched, 'has-success': !noteForm.c_subject.$invalid }">
                    <label class="control-label">Subject</label>
                    <input type="text" name="c_subject" class="form-control" required ng-model="note.c_subject" ng-minlength="10" />
                    <span style="color: red" ng-show="noteForm.c_subject.$dirty && noteForm.c_subject.$invalid">
                        <span ng-show="noteForm.c_subject.$error.required">Subject is required!</span>
                        <span ng-show="noteForm.c_subject.$error.minlength">Subject is should be less than 11 characters!</span>
                    </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
...
<div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-disabled="noteForm.$invalid" ng-click="sendForm()">OK</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
```

And here's my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/common_js/sample_app.js'); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    sampleApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $modal, $log) {

        $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

        $scope.open = function open(size) {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent',
                size: size,
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            });

        }

    });

    sampleApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance){

        /*
        $scope.ok = function () {
            alert('you clicked!');
        };
        */

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    });

    sampleApp.controller('NoteCtrl', function($scope) {

        //$scope.master = {c_subject: 'Lorem Ipsum Subject', c_message: 'Lorem Ipsum Message', c_sender: 'anonymous_phil'}
        //$scope.note = angular.copy($scope.master)

        $scope.sendForm = function ($scope) {
            console.log($scope) //undefined value
        }

        $scope.word_count = function () {
            //return 100 - $scope.c_message.length; // produce error because $scope.c_message can't access
        }

    });


</script>
```

And I am using this event to get the data but I got is undefined value:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-disabled="noteForm.$invalid" ng-click="sendForm()">OK</button>
```

and

```
$scope.sendForm = function ($scope) {
                console.log($scope) //undefined value
            }
```

I hope you can help me with this.

Here's the plunk for this: http://plnkr.co/edit/o7K1Db9oBzpfiMoYg3qm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this function, you should not pass in the parameter `$scope`:

```
$scope.sendForm = function ($scope) {
    alert($scope)
}
```

Because Angular will not inject the `$scope` for you! (Please refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di):

> DI is pervasive throughout Angular. You can use it when **defining**
>   **components** or when providing **`run` and `config` blocks for a module**.

Inside the function `sendForm`, the `$scope` refers to the parameter you give, which is `undefined`.

Change to:

```
$scope.sendForm = function () {
    alert($scope)
}
```

Then it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/wS073GWq7CGq1gaFpXEn?p=preview

Comment: Ok I already removed the parameter but how can I access the text inputs value? When i try to access this: console.log($scope.c_message) what I got is undefined

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent',
                size: size,
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                resolve: {
                  items: function () {
                   return $scope.note;
               } }
            });
    modalInstance.result.then(function (entity) {
      // do whatever you want to do with the returned entity
    }, function (e) {
       // error 
       console.log(e);
    });
  };
```

Comment: I tried to put a console.log below the comment //do whatever... but I didn't get any value.

Comment: Ok I will try to create a fiddle

Comment: You need to pass the result out by calling $modalInstance.close(result) in the modal controller

Comment: This is better than the selected answer. The other is far way from simplicity and exposes unnecessary data to outside the `$modalInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the `Plunkr` from Anik's answer and changed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/UI9jq3QE6U7YECKPmdYc?p=preview

For example, if you need to call a $http request, on its promise that'll be inside `sendForm()` method of `NoteCtrl` controller of the modal, you can call `$modalInstance.$close($scope.note)`, which will be evaluated on the `modalInstance.result.then(function (entity) {...});` of the other controller.